# Bitmap.getPixel в потоке

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Нужно получить из BitMap значения канала R всех пикселй, метод реализован ниже

```
        static Bitmap map;
        static int[,] Pixels;

         void BitmapGetPixels()
        {

             int i2=Convert.ToInt32(map.PhysicalDimension.Height),j2=Convert.ToInt32(map.PhysicalDimension.Width);

            for (int i = 0; i < i2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < j2; j++)
                  Pixels[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(map.GetPixel(i, j).R); // эта строка

                progressBar1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { progressBar1.PerformStep(); }));

          }
```

В указанной строке получаю следующую ошибку при выполнении:

**Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в System.Drawing.dll
Дополнительные сведения: В данный момент объект используется другим процессом.**

В чем дело? Почему тогда первые строки при работе с объектом map проходят, а после нескольких циклов с getPixel получаю ошибку? И как это исправить?

При отладке исключения не возникает, видимо потому, что метод GetPixel успевает полностью выполниться, прежде чем начнет работать снова

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы делаете неправильно. Попиксельная обработка всего `Bitmap`'а — жутко медленная вещь.

Делайте через `LockBits`, получайте копию всех данных в массив и там уже извлекайте то, что вам интересно. В конце [этой статьи](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) пример того, как нужно делать.

И да, убедитесь, что для вас слово stride — не пустой звук, без этого ничего не выйдет.

---

И ещё: не вызывайте ни в коем случае progress callback после **каждого** обработанного пикселя! Обработка одного пикселя — штука быстрая, и происходит много миллионов раз в вашем коде, а отправка сообщения в другой поток — штука по сравнению с этим дико дорогая. (Это всё равно как вы после каждого написанного оператора программы отмечали это новой бутылкой коньяка.) Отравляйте сообщения не чаще, чем 10 раз в секунду, или, скажем, каждый 1% от общей работы.